# How to optimize code that shows one block and hides others?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 blocks, when opening one, all should hide. I wrote the simplest code (I'm a beginner), I understand that it can and should be optimized. How can I do that?
I'm thinking of using "if else" construction, but not sure how to do it correctly.

```js
function openLink(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_link')[0].style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_images')[0].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_video')[0].style.display = 'none';
}

function openImages(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_images')[0].style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_link')[0].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_video')[0].style.display = 'none';
}

function openVideo(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_video')[0].style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_images')[0].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_link')[0].style.display = 'none';
}

function closeForm(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_link')[0].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_images')[0].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_video')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<a onclick="openLink()" href='#'>One</a>
<a onclick="openVideo()" href='#'>Two</a>
<a onclick="openImages()" href='#'>Three</a>


<div class="open_link" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="closeForm()">Save 1</button>
<button onclick="closeForm()">Close 1</button>
</div>

<div class="open_video" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="closeForm()">Save 2</button>
<button onclick="closeForm()" >Close 2</button>
</div>

<form class="open_images" style="display: none;">
<input onclick="closeForm()" value="Upload 3"/>
<button onclick="closeForm()" >Close 3</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate

Here is a start

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content");
document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const id = tgt.dataset.id;
  [...content.querySelectorAll("div")].forEach(div => {
    if (div.id !== id) div.classList.add("hide");
  })  
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("hide");
    
})

content.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("close")) {
    tgt.closest("div").classList.add("hide")
  }
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a data-id="link" href='#'>One</a>
  <a data-id="video" href='#'>Two</a>
  <a data-id="images" href='#'>Three</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="link" class="hide">
    <button type="button" id="save1">Save 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="close">Close 1</button>
  </div>

  <div id="video" class="hide">
    <button type="button" id="save2">Save 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="close">Close 2</button>
  </div>
  <div id="images" class="hide">
    <form>
      <input id="upload" value="Upload 3" />
      <button type="button" class="close">Close 3</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example

Answer (score -1):

You can sum up some of your redundant code into one function and pass parameters to it.

```js
function openAndClose(classBlock, classNone, classNone1) {
  document.getElementsByClassName(classBlock)[0].style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementsByClassName(classNone)[0].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName(classNone1)[0].style.display = 'none'
}

function closeForm(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_link')[0].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_images')[0].style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementsByClassName('open_video')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<a onclick="openAndClose('open_link', 'open_images', 'open_video')" href='#'>One</a>
<a onclick="openAndClose('open_video', 'open_images', 'open_link')" href='#'>Two</a>
<a onclick="openAndClose('open_images', 'open_link', 'open_video')" href='#'>Three</a>


<div class="open_link" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="closeForm()">Save 1</button>
<button onclick="closeForm()">Close 1</button>
</div>

<div class="open_video" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="closeForm()">Save 2</button>
<button onclick="closeForm()" >Close 2</button>
</div>

<form class="open_images" style="display: none;">
<input onclick="closeForm()" value="Upload 3"/>
<button onclick="closeForm()" >Close 3</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this but with your own ids and classes
.open are the div to open
id of the target is id of your div, you did this with classes

```
document.querySelectorAll(".open").forEach(div => {
        div.onclick = (e) => {
            switch (e.target.id) {
                case "open_link":
                    openLink()
                    break;
                case "open_video":
                    openVideo()
                    break;
                case "open_images":
                    openImages()
                break;
            }
        }
    })
```